# How can a program remember the time it was last run?

Tags: c++, filesystems, last-modified

I'm making a simple program that copies files created or modified since it was last run. What's the best way to store the time the program itself was last run? I was thinking it could have a text file that it would store the date and time in but is there a way that doesn't require external files? Windows has a "last modified" date but I don't know of a "last used" date.

Comment: The usual way is to either create a registry entry that stores info for your app (in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, because the last time run could differ between users) or in a file in the user's `%APPDATA%` folder.

Comment: If I did store it in a file, would it be more efficient to only modify the file arbitrarily and check the files last modified date as opposed to reading and writing a string containing the time the program was last run?

Comment: Relative to the rest of your program, the amount of time you spend opening, writing a timestamp, and closing the file is miniscule. Write something human-readable as well as machine.

Comment: @Celeritas What makes you concerned about the performance of a simple date compare. Also notice that its better to decode/encode a string than working with it directly.

Comment: You wan to "arbitrarily" modify *what* file? The text file itself? It's more difficult to set a file's last modified stamp than it is to save a file with a date, and no one said anything about a "string containing the time". Binary files work pretty easily, and take less storage to save the same data.

Comment: There is a "last accessed" timestamp, but it can be turned off (so that it's not updated). I'm not sure if it's on by default for executables. On my Windows 7 it's not updated, but I think maybe I turned off that thing.

Comment: This is what I mean. Option 1)Have a text file and in it write the time the program was executed. Any files older than the previous record will be copied Option 2)Arbitrarily modify the text file so that it's last modified date will correspond with the last time the program was run.
It sounds like option 1 is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any method requires a file or a modified file including the registry method suggested in the comments. While technically a file, the [Alternative Data Stream](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763) capability of NT file systems is one method. Here's a good description. http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-alternate-data-streams/

Comment: So your suggestion is to store an alternative data stream for the executable itself? That's not only more work, but it would require multiple entries (one for each user account) and more info (which user ran it last). I don't think this is a viable option for the question asked. (Not downvoting, but totally disagree with the strategy.)

Comment: @KenWhite  Petty easy to have one stream per user with a single last executed date, but I don't think this is a good way to solve the problem, but it is a way. Pretty much any way will require a file of some sort and as you suggest an entry per user.

Comment: This just seems like it's way too complex a solution for the question asked. What if the user doesn't have write access to the executable? If the question is as simple as "store the last file the app was run", it seems a quick file write to the local user's local or roaming profile folder would be much better (especially since the poster wasn't even sure how to achieve the task at all).

Comment: @KenWhite good points on security. I don't understand your to complex thing. I can write to an alternate stream from the command line and it's basically as simple as writing any file.

Comment: :-) I know. THe complexity comes from attaching multiple alt streams to the same file, meaning you now have to identify them with the current user somehow (APPDATA knows that already), there are issues with copying the file (do alt streams go with it, or do you leave them behind and start over). I wasn't talking about complexity in writing the streams themselves, but the other complexity involved.

Comment: OK, I get what your point, but this is a 'it depends'. I can see scenarios where you have the exact same application in different places that you want to track 'when last run'. At that point an APPDATA repo approach gets too complex. Good points all and all and giving the OP information is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm making a simple program that copies files created or modified since it was last run.

That's what the [archive flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit) is for. Windows will automatically set this flag whenever a file is created or modified.

Your program simply needs to skip files with the archive flag set, then copy and reset archive flags on the remaining files.

Comment: If you reset it, regular backups won't detect the change and back it up (especially on an incremental backup).

Comment: @KenWhite I don't think the regular Windows backup uses this flag anymore. Unmodified files being backed-up on my machine all seem to have the archive bit set. Of course, there may be other backup programs out there that still use this flag...

Comment: Windows Backup? Does anyone actually use that? ;-) I'm not downvoting, but this also doesn't handle the per-user situation either (and requires write access to all of the files involved in order to flip the archive bit - UAC anyone?).